# Django Secret Key Must Not Be Empty Error

Tags: ubuntu, django, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run django on AWS EC2 framework tensorflow_p36 which has its own virtualenv as tensorflow_p36. It is providing python3.6 as the language version. I found there was a conflict with mod_wsgi which was running on python3.5 so I had to reinstall it. Now the problem with mod_wsgi has gone but another problem -- Django secret key error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./manage.py", line 14, in 
>       application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
>     File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 135, in **init**
>       self.load_middleware()
>     File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 34, in load_middleware
>       for middleware_path in reversed(settings.MIDDLEWARE):
>     File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 79, in **getattr**
>       self._setup(name)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 66, in _setup
>       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 157, in **init**
>       mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>     File "", line 994, in _gcd_import
>     File "", line 971, in _find_and_load
>     File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>     File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>     File "", line 678, in exec_module
>     File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>     File "/var/www/picslo/picslo/settings.py", line 15, in 
>       django.setup()
>     File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 19, in setup
>       configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 79, in **getattr**
>       self._setup(name)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 66, in _setup
>       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 176, in **init**
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

**wsgi.py settings**

```
import os, sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/var/www/picslo')
# adjust the Python version in the line below as needed
sys.path.append('anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages')


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'picslo.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**000-default.conf**
ServerName picswics.com

```
    ServerAdmin info@picswics.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/picslo

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/picslo/picslo/wsgi.py

    WSGIDaemonProcess picslo python-path=/var/www/picslo python-home=anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36
    WSGIProcessGroup picslo

    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/picslo/static/img/logo/logo.png
    <Directory /var/www/picslo/picslo>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /var/www/picslo/static/
    <Directory /var/www/picslo/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Does your `settings.py` contains a `SECRET_KEY` variable (that is not empty)?

Comment: settings.py already contains a SECRET_KEY